# showing product on custom page gives error

Tags: magento-1.9, module

i am showing product on custom page created via modules

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\related.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>   
    <layout version="0.1.0">   
      <related_index_index>   
        <reference name="root">   
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
        </reference>   
        <reference name="content">   
          <block type="catalog/product" name="related_index" template="related/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   
      </related_index_index>   
    </layout>
```

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\related\index.phtml
i just copied list.phtml content here with few modification

no it gives error

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function getStoreLabel() on a non-object in app\design\frontend\themefolder\themefile\template\catalog\product\price.phtml on line 53

i got few answer but i do not want to modify core files please suggest way to fix it

Line no 53 of price.html

```
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
```

**Updated code for my \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\related\index.phtml**

Here i am show all related products of product

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
$product = $model->load($product_id);

// Get all related product ids of $product.
$allRelatedProductIds = $product->getRelatedProductIds();

    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $code  = $store->getCode();

?>
<?php if(!count($allRelatedProductIds)): ?>
<?php foreach ($allRelatedProductIds as $id): 
        $_product = $model->load($id);
        ?>
<h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName();?></a></h3>
 <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Yes! Because you're saying its a type of catalog/product .. That function getStoreLabel() does not exist in the block class app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php

Comment: The error is thrown from the price template though, which is likely a child block. We have no reference from that answer that it's even calling the method against `$this`. We'd need to know whats on the lines ~53 of `price.phtml`.

Comment: This is not enough information,  if you are just loading a single product then why you are using list.phtml file code, you should use view.phtml
and if you need to use list.phtml code then where are you creating collection of products?
One more thing if you needed only one product then how are you loading that product?
Please provide full information what are you trying to do else no one can help here

Comment: @Saurabh updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bellow code in file `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\related.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
    <related_index_index>   
        <reference name="root">   
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
        </reference>   
        <reference name="content">   
          <block type="catalog/product_list" name="related_index" template="related/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   
    </related_index_index>   
</layout>
```

**OR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
    <related_index_index>   
        <reference name="root">   
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
        </reference>   
        <reference name="content">   
          <block type="catalog/product_related" name="related_index" template="related/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   
    </related_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Also add bellow code in file `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\related\index.phtml`

```
<?php
  $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $product_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
  $product = $model->load($product_id);

  // Get all related product ids of $product.
    $allRelatedProductIds = $product->getRelatedProductIds();

    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $code  = $store->getCode();

?>
<?php if(count($allRelatedProductIds)): ?>
<?php foreach ($allRelatedProductIds as $id): ?>
    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);?>
    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName();?></a></h3>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: hey but it show same price for all products now

Comment: can you share \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\related\index.phtml file code

Comment: already shared pls check

Comment: Updated ans pls  check now

Comment: can you tell what exact you changed but it works

Comment: i have added only one line code in foreach loop : <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);?>

Answer (score 2):

Find simple solution and its work:

Open this file : app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Find this code:

```
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
```

And replace it with below:

```
$specialPriceAttr = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price');
if (!is_null($specialPriceAttr)) {
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
} else {
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = '';
}
```

Reference: http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/call-to-a-member-function-getstorelabel-in-price-phtml/

Answer (score 0):

we had problem with a widget coming from MGS Megamenu (class `MGS_Megamenu_Block_Product`).
Their widget extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` that only is a dummy block that crashes if `getPriceHtml` is called in phtml template underlay. Maybe that block should extend rather `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`.

We solved it by follow hack:

```
// HACK
//class MGS_Megamenu_Block_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product
class MGS_Megamenu_Block_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
...
```